# HTML5 : Div getting cropped while Dragging

Tags: html, css, transform, scale, drag

In HTML5 When Parent Div has -webkit-transform scale applied and child is draggable. Then while dragging child, child overlay is getting cropped.

What should be the right implementation for this.

Chrome Specific Issue

Comment: clickeble http://jsfiddle.net/CF7dq/

Comment: doesnt happen in firefox for me